# tooltipster jQuery plugin not working if not div

Tags: tooltipster

I'm trying to use tooltipster  jQuery plugin, but it doesn't work for  or  tag :

I've just tried this simple code :

```
<div id="my-tooltip">
This div has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!
</div>
```

--> div works fine

```
<select id="my-tooltip" name="select">
<option value="value1">Valeur 1</option>
<option value="value2" selected>Valeur 2</option>
<option value="value3">Valeur 3</option>
</select>
```

--> select doesn't work

```
<span id="my-tooltip">
test with span
</span>
```

--> span doesn't work

Could you please help me ?
[here is my page](http://printyshirt.wytaa.fr/index.php/fr/shop/femme/tee-shirt-femme-col-v-31-detail)

thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code and site the issue is due to your multiple use of the id `my-tooltip`. IDs should only be used once to identify **one** node. A simple test can be done to prove this using jQuery, try running this on the page:

```
jQuery('#my-tooltip')
```

You'll see that only one node is returned, this is the one that has your initialised tooltip.

To fix this you'll need to change your nodes to use **classes**, i.e.

```
<div class="my-tooltip">
    This div has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!
</div>

<select class="my-tooltip" name="select">
    <option value="value1">Valeur 1</option>
    <option value="value2" selected>Valeur 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Valeur 3</option>
</select>

<span class="my-tooltip">test with span</span>
```

In your tooltipster setup, you'll want to have the following selector and options enabled:

```
jQuery('.my-tooltip').tooltipster({
    // Original setup
    content: jQuery('<span><img src="/../../../popup.png" /> <strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span>')

    // Additional options
    multiple: true,
    contentAsHTML: true
});
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: @wytaa Excellent, good to hear! Feel free to accept my answer (the tick underneath the up/down arrows) - this will help with the answer for any other visitors asking the same question :)